# Error with shutil.move when moving files over directories

Tags: python, shutil

I am new to Python and trying to write a script that will sort out cluttered folders into subfolders depending on filetype. For some reason I am getting an error with **shutil.move** when trying to run my script.

Please excuse the non-efficient code - I have changed around lots to try and debug! Please find attached my code and error message.

```
import os
import shutil

filename =  os.getcwd()

print filename
print filename + '/Images'


#sort IMAGES
if os.path.exists(filename + '/Images'):
    print "Yes, Image folder exists"
else:
    print "No, it does not exists "
    print "Creating new directory for Images"
    os.makedirs(filename + '/Images')
filename1 = filename + '/Images'
#os.chdir(filename1)

for file in os.listdir(filename):
    if file.endswith(".JPG"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".png"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".gif"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)

#sort Videos
if os.path.exists(filename + '/Videos'):
    print "Yes, Videos folder exists"
else:
    print "No, it does not exists "
    print "Creating new directory for Videos"
    os.makedirs(filename + '/Videos')
filename1 = filename + '/Videos'
#os.chdir(filename1)

for file in os.listdir(filename):
    if file.endswith(".mov"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".avi"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".mkv"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)


#sort SONGS
if os.path.exists(filename + '/Music'):
    print "Yes, Music folder exists"
else:
    print "No, it doesnot exists "
    print "Creating new directory for Music"
    os.makedirs(filename + '/Music')
filename1 = filename + '/Music'
#os.chdir(filename1)

for file in os.listdir(filename):
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".wav"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)
    elif file.endswith(".wma"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1)


#sort DOCUMENTS
if os.path.exists(filename + '/Documents'):
    print "Yes, Documents folder exists"
else:
    print "No, it doesnot exists "
    print "Creating new directory for Documents"
    os.makedirs(filename + '/Documents')
filename1 = filename + '/Documents'
#os.chdir(filename1)

#check if it is neccessary to create new sub-directories for document types
contains_pdf = False
contains_doc = False
contains_ppt = False

for file in os.listdir(filename1):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        contains_pdf = True
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        contains_doc = True
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        contains_doc = True
    if file.endswith(".ppt"):
        contains_ppt = True

#create subdirectories if does not exist
if os.path.exists(filename + '/Documents/PDF') == False and contains_pdf == True:
    os.makedirs(filename1 + '/PDF')
elif os.path.exists(filename + '/Documents/DOC') == False and contains_doc == True:
    os.makedirs(filename1 + '/DOC')
elif os.path.exists(filename + '/Documents/PPT') == False and contains_ppt == True:
    os.makedirs(filename1 + '/PPT')

filename2 = filename1
#move subtypes of documents in correct folders - THIS IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR!
for file in os.listdir(filename1):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        filename2 = filename1 + '/PDF'
        shutil.move(file, filename2)
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1 + '/DOC')
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1 + '/DOC')
    if file.endswith(".ppt"):
        shutil.move(file,filename1 + '/PPT')
    filename2 = filename1
```

I can't figure it out. This is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "organise.py", line 104, in <module>
    shutil.move(file,filename2)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '03_Anesthetic considerations in severe ankylosing.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.

I was passing a file name where I needed to pass a path. eg.

```
for file in os.listdir(filename):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        shutil.move(filename + file, filename1 + '/PDF/' + file)
    if file.endswith(".PDF"):
        shutil.move(filename + file, filename1 + '/PDF/' + file)
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        shutil.move(filename + file, filename1 + '/DOC/' + file)
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.move(filename + file, filename1 + '/DOC/' + file)
```